Unable to set the content to the ckeditor
I am using version 5 of CKEditor and I have an issue where I can load the Ckeditor in the UI but am unable to see the content in it after setting the data
If I add the links from the Editor menu, the link is getting added but not displaying the editor.
I am setting the data in the editor using the below code.
applicationName.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
    require:'?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) (
     
        if (!ngModel) return;
        
        ClassicEditor
            .create(element (01)
            .then (editor => {
        
                editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                
                ngModel.$setViewValue (editor.getData());
        
                if (ClassicEditor.instances.requestDetail && sessionStorage.getItem("ViewResponse_requestDetail"))(
                    ClassicEditor.instances.requestDetail.setData(sessionStorage.getItem("ViewResponse_requestDetail")
                );
        }
    });

But the control is not going inside the editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => { method, its skipping the method
Using the above method I am fetching the values from the database and setting them in ck editor
Please help me in identifying the issue
